# How do you install library "iberty" for MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos

Trying to compile `backward-cpp` https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp for MacOS Mojave, and getting this:

```
ld: library not found for -liberty
```

Which is straighforward in and of itself, but I can't seem to find how to install it?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160517/configuration-error-iberty-library-not-found

says to install `binutils` unfortunately installing it using brew `brew install binutils` does not include the `iberty` library.
It seems `libiberty` is included in the `gcc` compiler (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libiberty), but I use `clang` by default. Is it not possible to use `libiberty` if using clang?

I've tried using latest gcc

```
gcc --version
gcc (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0_1) 9.3.0
```

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc
```

But to no avail, same issue unfortunately. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Homebrew for that. First add `--enable-install-libiberty` to the configure option of binutils using:

```
brew edit binutils
```

then reinstall it using:

```
brew reinstall -s binutils
```